# Image Stuck on Screen - 'Update is Ready' - Unable to delete

Tags: windows-7

[image]

I'm unable to figure out how to delete the above hanging graphic.

As far as I can tell, it appears to have been stuck on my desktop from some previous software I've already deleted/uninstalled from my PC.

It's been months since it's been there at the lower right corner of the screen and and I've attempted changing screen resolution to try to make it disappear, but that only placed the hanging image more towards the center of the screen making it ever more annoying and unbearable!

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What software is it from?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I think it may have been from some of those add on thingy's they sneak install when I tried some free software, but it didn't show up until long after I had deleted it.

Comment: Have you ever used Lightshot or Free Sound Recorder?

Comment: yes. Definitely the Free sound recorder. Let me try the tip below.

Comment: You can check for the presence of the updater (under FRS director in Program Files). If it works for you can can -- but are under no obligation to -- upvote/accept the answer. Good luck! :)

Comment: Free Sound Recorder Updater is probably causing this

From your comments, it seems to be Free Sound recorder which is the culprit. Check for it at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Free Sound Recorder\FFProductUpdater.exe and you can deal with it using either of the methods below.

Comment: Thank you SOOO MUCH! yes, it was Free Sound Recorder Updater !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Free Sound Recorder Updater is probably causing this

From your comments, it seems to be Free Sound recorder which is the culprit. Check for it at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Free Sound Recorder\FFProductUpdater.exe` and you can deal with it using either of the methods below.

### Using FRST

Checking for the phrasing of the suggested update gives another user who had a similar problem to you:

> My issue is the following:
>
> A window opens when my computer starts: It is labeled "Update is ready> Update and benefit from enchancement and fixed."

*([original in French](https://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-34862963-mise-a-jour-inconnue) - [Google Translate version](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.commentcamarche.net%2Fforum%2Faffich-34862963-mise-a-jour-inconnue&edit-text=&act=url))*

[image: update is ready]

*(image from above thread)*

Recommended there is the [Farbar Recovery Tool](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=fr&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://www.malekal.com/tutoriel-farbar-recovery-scan-tool-frst/&xid=17259,15700023,15700124,15700149,15700168,15700186,15700191,15700201,15700208&usg=ALkJrhgT9wPqg7JUP4kY8wcoXaXeHvdZNw) (another Google Translate link), which the original user says solved the issue.

There was a suggestion that **Lightshot** or **Free Sound Recorder** may have been to blame.

### Or use `msconfig`

If you are not keen on using a potentially foreign-language tool, you can use `msconfig` to see what items are being loaded on startup:

1. Open the `Run` dialog (<kbd>Win+r</kbd>)
2. Type `msconfig` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Go to the `Startup` tab and uncheck items you are suspicious of

It will look something like the following, but likely with additional entries:

[image: msconfig example]

*(example `msconfig` Startup section with one entry from a Virtual Machine)*

'Suspicious' is an admittedly broad / vague term, but loom for entries that seem to be updaters, or are from software you know you have removed, or that you dont recognise (do a web search for these before disabling/removing them).

---

**tl;dr**: Possibilities include **Lightshot** and **Free Sound Recorder** as potential culprits. Use `FRST` or `msconfig` to disable whatever caused this

Answer (score 0):

1. Bring the pc task manager up(in windows= ctrl+alt+del).
2. choose the "processes" option, & then choose the "free sound recorder" option.
3. Then choose the "end process" option.
4. Get a third party uninstaller like iobit(the free version).
5. With iobit locate the directory as follows:
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Free Sound Recorder\FFProductUpdater.exe
6. Choose the "uninstall" option.
7. Delete the remaining files left over from free sound recorder(optional)
   located in the directory above.